# Append file name in local storage to saveJSONObject sequentially

Tags: java, json, processing

I'm using processing to scrape data from the web using an API call to get a JSON object every minute this is done with the following;

```
JSONObject raw = loadJSONObject(url); 
events = raw.getJSONArray("theThingiWant");
```

I then use `saveJSONObject(raw, "data/scraped"+".json");` to save this object.

I'm aware that in processing that there is [saveframe()](https://processing.org/reference/saveFrame_.html) function which allows you to save frames in sequence to a number format of your choice and had hoped that saveJSONObject would have this in it but it doesn't.

What I want to do is save multiple JSON objects sequentially so my data folder contains scrape001, scrape002 etc. Is there a function for this or would it be done by retrieving and appending the last saved file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to your `millis()` solution, you could also just keep track of an `int` value, use it when generating a file name, and increment it whenever you save a file.

Something like this:

```
int files = 0;

void draw(){
  saveJSONObject(whatever, "scraped" + files + ".json");
  files++;
}
```

You could also use the `frameCount` variable:

```
void draw(){
  saveJSONObject(whatever, "scraped" + frameCount+ ".json");
  files++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i've got a working solution to what i wanted to do as follows;

I know i'm calling the API and getting a new JSON object every minute. I can use this in conjunction with the millis() function in processing as below

`saveJSONObject(raw, "data/scraped00"+(millis()/60000)+".json");`

What this does is save the JSONobject then append it with a unqiue number generated by millis() dividing that by 60000 converts from milliseconds to minutes. This means the file will not overwrite the last save but generate a new file in increments of one minute.